# react js chat aplication socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I'm learning to program chat web, using react js, node js, socket.io and I'm copyng of this repository:

```
https://github.com/adrianhajdin/project_chat_application
```

and I apply git clone and install dependecies and whe I'm going to run this's showing in console:

```
polling-xhr.js:269 GET https://project-chat-application.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Ncf_HGB net::ERR_FAILED
```

so I checked this variable:

```
const ENDPOINT = 'https://project-chat-application.herokuapp.com/';
```

and I got this error when I try to get in 'https://project-chat-application.herokuapp.com/'

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail
```

what can I do to fix it??

Comment: You need to run the server component yourself, and point your client at your server. This URL seems like it was a placeholder app for the developer to run an instance of their server which is not currently running.

Comment: yes I'm running server to..... and about url, I can create one myself?? how

Comment: If you are jsut testing on your local network, use IP addresses instead of DNS names. `http://192.168.1.140:8888/`; where the IP is the address of your computer, and the port is the CP port the server is configured to listen on. If you deploy it to heroku, they will give you a DNS name.

Comment: yes! I only want test it and late  study how is it work..... i used url  const ENDPOINT = 'http://192.168.1.140:8888/';    and this error is showing net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: My URL was only an example. You need to replace the IP with the local IP of your computer, and the port with the port the service binds to.

Comment: ahmmmm I get it! I get it

Comment: It looks like the server uses [port 5000 by default](https://github.com/adrianhajdin/project_chat_application/blob/master/server/index.js#L51).

Comment: so I can use something like: http://localhost:5000:8888/

Comment: `http://localhost:5000/`

Comment: yes!!!! it work bro!!  thanks so much